# How to pass parameter between functions in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters

I have this peace of code

```
    var FACEBOOK = 'facebook';

    $scope.handle_credentials = function (network) {
      hello(network).api('me').then(function (json) {
        dbService.handle_credentials(json)
      });
    };
    $scope.loginFB = function () {
      hello(FACEBOOK).login(handle_credentials(FACEBOOK))
    };
```

But I am having this error

```
handle_credentials is not defined
```

How can I pass parameter between angular JS functions

Comment: You should do `hello(FACEBOOK).login($scope.handle_credentials(FACEBOOK))`.

Comment: What is `dbService`? Plus to invoke handle_credentials you need to invoke it like `$scope.handle_credentials`

Comment: can you send complete controller code? Is above code in Controller?

Answer (score 2):

You have did't implement js `handle_credentials` function in your `controller`. You just assigned the function into your `$scope` object.

So you should call the function from `$scope` object

```
hello(FACEBOOK).login($scope.handle_credentials(FACEBOOK));
```

Answer (score 1):

If both functions are in the same scope you can call `$scope.handre_credentials` inside `loginFB` function:

```
$scope.loginFB = function () {
  hello(FACEBOOK).login($scope.handle_credentials(FACEBOOK))
};
```